# How can I stack this Z-index configuration?

Tags: html, css, firefox, z-index

I have a situation whereby:

My Hierarchy is:

```
box1: (z-index: 5000)
  -(other parent elements)
    -box1_child (z-index: 5001)
box2 (z-index: 5000)
  -(other parent elements)
    -box2_child (z-index: 5002)
```

So obviously, I want box1 and box2 at the same level.
I want box1_child to sit over box2.
I want box2_cihld to sit over box1_child.

But it's not working (in FF4), basically, box1_child isn't sitting over box2.

Is this possible, (on the more recent browsers?)

All elements have a non-static position.

Comment: Show the real CSS and the real HTML please. And why are you using FF4? FF4 had problems and was quickly replaced by FF5. For a very stable old FF, I think you'd best use FF3.6.

Comment: Anyway, I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AX5Wr/1/) that I think does what you want (although it's bound to be less complex than your site - e.g. I only need 2 different Z-index levels instead of over 5000) and the browsers I have here (IE9, FF22, Op12, Ch30) all behave as expected.

Comment: @Mr Lister - put your comment into an answer, get the cred for it...

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure if that was anywhere close to what your page looked like though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if two adjacent elements have the same Z-index, they still have a certain stacking order: the one that comes later is drawn over the first.

Using this, you can use this CSS (simplified) to stack the elements in the way you want.

```
#box1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:auto;
}
#box1_child {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#box2{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:auto;
}
#box2_child {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Then box2 is drawn on over box1 (if they overlap at all) and box2_child is drawn over box1_child, but both children are drawn over the parent boxes.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AX5Wr/1/).

Tested on various newer browsers. I don't have Firefox 4 here, so can't confirm that it doesn't work there.

Edit: Seems I was wrong in my assumption that `z-index:0` is the same as `auto`. Indeed it doesn't work with 0, so it won't work with 5000 either. My apologies.

Comment: Oh... Sorry, but it won't work like I wrote. It will only work with `z-index:auto`, so your original plan with `5000` is out. I edited. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Things with non-auto z-index form a new stacking context that stacks atomically.

So to get the effect you want you need box1 and box2 to have auto z-index...  Note that a positive z-index will stack above auto, so that should give you the behavior you want.